# How to make my ajax polling run for 5 times only then terminate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do is do now is instead of infinite ajax polling i want to do is make it run for 5 times then terminate the ajax infinite polling.

My problem is it doesn't work as i wanted. Can anyone help me with this?

ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var = x;

    var countTimer = setInterval(function () {
     if(x++ === 5){
      clearInterval(countTimer);  
       }else{
      codeValue()
     }
    }, 500)
    function codeValue() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'codeTime.php',
            dataType: "JSON",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#count").val(result.user_code);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: var = x; ....do you mean var x = 0;

Comment: This shouldn't run at all with that syntax error; check your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `var x = 0`

I'd personally do it like this:

```
    var x = 0;
    var countTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if(x === 5){
            clearInterval(countTimer);  
        }else{
          codeValue();
          x++;
        }
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not define x, u have `var = x;` which should be a syntax error. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var countTimes = 0;
    var numberOfTimes = 5;

    var countTimer = 0;
    countTimer = setInterval(function () {

        countTimes++;
        if(countTimes > numberOfTimes){
           clearInterval(countTimer); 
        }else{
            codeValue();
        }
    }, 500);

    function codeValue() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'codeTime.php',
            dataType: "JSON",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#count").val(result.user_code);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```